# Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Item[]>: Rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

Here `ItemService`
item.service.ts

```
export const items = (state: any = [], {type, payload}) => {
   switch (type) {
     default:
        return state;
   }
};

export interface Item {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   description: string;
};

export interface AppStore {
   items: Item[];
   selectedItem: Item;
};

@Injectable()
export class ListService {
   items: Observable<Array<Item>>;
   private listModel: ItemList = new ItemList();

   constructor(private itemListApi: ItemListApi, private store: Store<AppStore>) {
       this.items = store.select('items');===>Error

    }
}
```

I'm getting an error in `this.items`. The error is "Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable". What went wrong? Any help on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you defined `items` as `Observable<Array<Item>>` while `store.select('items')` probably returns `Observable<T>`.

You can use type casting to tell the compiler what you're expecting it to return:

```
this.items = <Observable<Item[]>>store.select('items');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
this.items = store.select<Array<Item>>('items');
```